# Wrapper function that conditionally returning promise or callback

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
async function wait(callback){
  var awaited = await giveError();
  return returner(awaited, callback)
}


function giveError(){throw new Error('oops')}
```

I was tasked to create the `returner` function there, that would return a promise if there was no callback, and call the callback if it does exist

if `returner` does nothing but return its first argument, it would return a promise, as desired

```
async function returner(awaited, callback){
  console.log('triggering returner')
  if(!callback){
    return awaited
  } else {
    console.log('there is a callback')
  }
}

wait().then(console.log).catch(err=>{
  console.log('correct error catching here for async \n\n')
})

// prints 'correct error catching here for async'
```

the problem is that I have difficulty catching the error if there is a callback (with the assumption that `awaited` is a promise)

```
wait(function(err, val){
  console.log('callback error handling', err, val)
})

async function returner(awaited, callback){
  console.log('triggering returner')
  if(!callback){
    return awaited
  } else {
    awaited
    .then(val=>{
      callback(null, val)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      callback(err)
    })
  }
}

// gives UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: oops
```

I have questions:

why does 'triggering returner' never print?

is `awaited` a promise? If not, is it possible at all to write the `returner` function?

Comment: `async` will ***always*** return a `Promise`.

Comment: You cannot do it in the `returner`. It's too late at that stage because `wait` will always return a Promise (due to `async`). You must do it in `wait()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does 'triggering returner' never print?

Because `await` will behave like `throw` if the promise it is waiting for rejects. Therefore the code terminates there and the error bubbles up, the `return returner(..)` is never reached.

> is awaited a promise?

No its the resolved value of the promise.

---

I would actually write a  function that wraps the async function itself and takes the callback:

```
  const withCallback = fn => (...args) => {
    const last = args[args.length - 1];
    if(typeof last === "function") {
      return fn(...args.slice(0, -1))
         .then(res => last(null, res))
         .catch(last);
   } else {
      return fn(.. args);
   }
 };
```

That way you can write it as:

```
 const wait = withCallback(async function wait(){
   var awaited = await giveError();
   return "result";
 });
```

That allows you to do:

```
 wait().then(/*...*/).catch(/*...*/)
 // As well as
 wait(function(error, result) { /*...*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions will ***always*** return a `Promise`.  If you want to configure your function's return type to vary based on the arguments, you will need to do so manually:

```js
function foo(cb) {
  if (typeof cb !== "function") {
    return Promise.resolve("hello");
  } else {
    return cb("hello");
  }
}

foo(v => console.log(v));
foo().then(v => console.log(v));
```